# Python add a new column and fill with values conditional on another column

Tags: python, performance, dataframe

Python noob here. In the dataframe below, I want to add a new column that has values dependent on the values in col2.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 10, 9], 'col2': [3, 4, 5, 6]})

   col1  col2
0     1     3
1     2     4
2    10     5
3     9     6
```

Add a new column 'col3' such that - If value in: col2 is <5, populate with 'In', >5 populate with 'Out', =5 populate with 5. Desired output is as below.

```
   col1  col2 col3
0     1     3   In
1     2     4   In
2    10     5    5
3     9     6  Out
```

I have been able to do this using a for-loop but that does not seem to be efficient on a large dataset. Any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

I find 3 ways to do this: using `np.where`, `pd.loc` and `pd.apply` (as well suggested by @OO7 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61802218/12882660))

```
def using_where(df):
    df['col3'] = np.where(df['col2']>5, 'Out', np.where(df['col2']<5, 'In', 5))
    return df

def using_apply(df):
    df['col3'] = df['col2'].apply(lambda x: 5 if x == 5 else ('In' if x < 5 else 'Out'))
    return df

def using_loc(df):
    df['col3'] = 5
    df.loc[df['col2']>5, 'col3'] = 'Out'
    df.loc[df['col2']<5, 'col3'] = 'In'
    return df
```

I profiled them all, and they seem to have different performances depending on the `size` of the `dataframe`:

```
size = 10**4
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': np.random.randint(0, 10, size), 'col2': np.random.randint(0, 10, size)})
%timeit using_where(df)
%timeit using_apply(df)
%timeit using_loc(df)
```

Using `size = 10**4` outputs:

```
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.97 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 2.11 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 4.14 ms per loop
```

Using `size = 10**5` outputs:

```
100 loops, best of 3: 18.6 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 17.5 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 11.9 ms per loop
```

In conclusion, I would say you should try this profiling yourself with you actual `dataframe` and choose the fastest method for your application.
Hope this helps!

Comment: @GunmaRex Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2,10,9], 'col2': [3, 4,5,6]})
df['col3'] = df['col2'].apply(lambda x: '5' if x == 5 else ('In' if x < 5 else "Out"))
df
```

[image]